# Make div appear or disappear with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to make a few divs behave the way I want them to. Here is my relevant HTML:

```
<ul class="services">
<li class="business-formation" id="services-li-1">Business Formation</li>
<li class="domestic-relations" id="services-li-2">Domestic Relations</li>
<li class="estate-probate" id="services-li-3">Estate & Probate</li>
</ul>

<div class="business-formation-list" id="business-formation-list">
<ul>
<li>Items go here</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="domestic-relations-list" id="domestic-relations-list">
<ul>
<li>Items go here</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="estate-probate-list" id="estate-probate-list">
<ul>
<li>Items go here</i>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want the divs to appear and disappear when the corresponding li is clicked (they are links). Here is my Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('services-li-1').style.cursor = "pointer";
document.getElementById('services-li-2').style.cursor = "pointer";
document.getElementById('services-li-3').style.cursor = "pointer";
const div1 = document.querySelector('business-formation-list');
const div2 = document.querySelector('domestic-relations-list');
const div3 = document.querySelector('estate-probate-list');
const click2 = document.getElementById('services-li-2');

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
if (event.click2.className = 'domestic-relations') {
div1.style.display = 'none';
div2.style.display = 'block';
div3.style.display = 'none';
}
});
```

This doesn't make anything happen, but what I wanted it to do is to make the second div appear when the li with the class name "domestic-relations" is clicked. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `querySelector`, you need to tell it that it's a class. You do that by adding `.` before the class in question.

So `document.querySelector('business-formation-list')` should be `document.querySelector('.business-formation-list')`.

However, if you're only using it once, it should be an ID, not a class.

Comment: I would also fix the typo: `if (event.click2.className === 'domestic-relations')`

Comment: Thanks! I do plan to use them more than once, so I left them as querySelector, but I added the . to show it as a class. I also fixed the = to ===.  It's still not working - any other suggestions?

Comment: Like @RaphaMex said, you'll want to change the line he provided. The class names don't match up. And if this answer helped you out, would you mind accepting it? It gives you rep as well.

Answer (score 0):

Im also fairly new to this and had a similar problem to yours. I came up with a solution, so it might help you as well. The solution is quite long so I hope you can bear with me.

first thing is to change your your div class "domestic/estate/business" to just "list". When you're doing the css for it, you'll want to apply the same style to them. If you need more styling, you can always target the IDs or add another css class.

Once you've done that, apply to that list "display: none;". This will hide all your ul's at once.

The javascript looks something like this. i've added some description as to why I chose to do what I did.

```
var serviceType = document.querySelectorAll(".serviceType");
var serviceTypeArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(serviceType); // this will 
 //change your serviceType from a nodelist to an Array.
var serviceDescription = document.querySelectorAll(".list"); // to grab the 
 //list of descriptions and make it into an "array"

for ( i = 0 ; i < serviceTypeArray.length ; i++) {
 var services = serviceTypeArray[i]; // I created this variable to store the 
   // variable "i"
 services.addEventListener( "click" , displayServices); }
  // created this "for loop" to loop through every element inside the array 
 //and give it the "click" function

function displayServices() {
  var servicePosition = serviceTypeArray.indexOf(this); // when we click the 
    // event, "this" will grab the position of the clicked item in the array
  if (serviceTypeArray[servicePosition].hasAttribute("id") == false) { // 
   //  the hasAttribute returns values of true/false, since initially the 
   // serviceTypeArray didn't have the "id" , it returns as false
  serviceTypeArray[servicePosition].setAttribute( "id" , "hide"); // I've 
   // added the "setAttribute" function as a unique indicator to allow 
   // javascript to easily hide and show based on what we are clicking
  serviceDescription[servicePosition].style.display = "block"; // When you 
   //click one of the serviceType, it returns an the index number (aka the 
   // position it is inside the arrayList)
   //this gets stored inside servicePosition(aka the actual number gets 
  //  stored).
  // Since i've made an array to store the the description of each service, 
  // their position in the array correspond with the service's position 
  //inside the serviceType array made earlier; therefore, when I press one 
  // particular serviceType (ie i clicked on "business formation"), the 
  // appropriate text will pop up because the position of both the name and 
  // its description are in the same position in both arrays made
 } else if (serviceTypeArray[servicePosition].hasAttribute("id") == true ) { 
  //since the serviceType now has an attribute, when we check it, it'll come 
  // back as true
    serviceTypeArray[servicePosition].removeAttribute("id"); //we want to 
    // remove the id so next time we click the name again, the first "if" 
    // condition is checked
     serviceDescription[servicePosition].style.display = "none"; //this is    
     //  so that the display goes back to "none"
      }
    }
```

This will allow to click any of the names and display/hide them at will. you can even show 2/3 or all three of them, it's up to you. I hope this helps and I hope the explanation is clear enough! 
   Let me know if you have any questions for this!